# Make the Hide Communities feature apply to the network profile too

Tags: feature-request, network-profile

The "Hide Communities" page (on the "Edit profile & Settings" tab of your profile) says that communities you have hidden will not appear in a couple sections of your profile:

> Choose which communities will appear in the Communities and Top Network Posts sections of your profile
>
> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list and Top Network Posts.

I checked my network profile and I could still see my hidden communities in all of the tabs there (top, accounts, reputation, activity, favorites).  I think the "Hide Communities" feature should also apply to your network profile (only for other users - when you visit your own network profile you should still see everything).

Comment: Also, shouldn't it also be bi-directional? I.e., if I've hidden my SO profile from SE, shoudn't my SE profile be hidden from SO?

Comment: I agree. I thought the "Hide Communities" applied across the board, meaning there would no longer be access to that information. I now understand that it only applies to the Meta profile, but think this is a valid request. I hope you raise it again when the right opportunity arises!